# Antd: sidemenu with side sub-menu

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

Using Antd, I am trying to create the menu attached below, using the existing components with the least amount of custom code as possible.

I have tried some implementation but it's just cheating xd -_-

I put a menu component next to a sider layout and toggled the sider layout on item click but that does not seem like a good solution

Any suggestion on how this can be implemented? The submenu should overlay the content of the page as well.

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu, Icon, Button, Layout } from "antd";

const { SubMenu } = Menu;

const { Header, Content, Sider } = Layout;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false
  };

  toggleCollapsed = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <div style={{ minHeight: 800 }}>
          <Menu
            defaultSelectedKeys={["1"]}
            defaultOpenKeys={["sub1"]}
            mode="inline"
            theme="dark"
            inlineCollapsed={true}
            style={{ minHeight: 800 }}
          >
            <Menu.Item key="1">
              <Icon type="pie-chart" />
              <span>Option 1</span>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">
              <Icon type="desktop" />
              <span>Option 2</span>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">
              <Icon type="inbox" />
              <span>Option 3</span>
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </div>
        <Sider> 
        <Menu
          mode="inline"
          defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}
          defaultOpenKeys={['sub1']}
          style={{ height: '100%', borderRight: 0 }}
        >
          <SubMenu
            key="sub1"
            title={
              <span>
                <Icon type="user" />
                subnav 1
              </span>
            }
          >
            <Menu.Item key="1">option1</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">option2</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3">option3</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="4">option4</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
          <SubMenu
            key="sub2"
            title={
              <span>
                <Icon type="laptop" />
                subnav 2
              </span>
            }
          >
            <Menu.Item key="5">option5</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="6">option6</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="7">option7</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="8">option8</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
          <SubMenu
            key="sub3"
            title={
              <span>
                <Icon type="notification" />
                subnav 3
              </span>
            }
          >
            <Menu.Item key="9">option9</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="10">option10</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="11">option11</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="12">option12</Menu.Item>
          </SubMenu>
        </Menu>
        </Sider>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

[**Side menu with side sub menu**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbuLU.png)